# Where are the Visual Studio 2013 Diagnostic Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, memory-profiling

I'm searching for a tool window for hours and I cannot find it. (see http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-29-92-metablogapi/3386.Screenshot1_5F00_FullWindow_5F00_thumb_5F00_3CF6D767.png)

I found it in the Visual Studio 2015 Preview (I just installed), but I am 100% sure that I also had it in Visual Studio 2013 before. However, I cannot find it any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see CPU Usage, Memory Usage etc. you can go to the Performance and Diagnostics hub by going to **Debug> Performance and Diagnostics** or by pressing Alt + F2. I'm not sure it's identical to the window in the screenshot you posted, but it should give you the same information.

This blog post might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's indeed this view. For some reason, it's greyed out in my Visual Studio at work (it's under the "not applicable tools"). When I open the same project on my notebook, everything works as expected. In the Visual Studio 2015, it's a normal tool window which can be opened during debugging...

Answer (score 1):

Diagnostic Tools while debugging are new in Visual Studio 2015. While there are similar tools in the VS2013 Performance and Diagnostics tool window, the project support between those tools and the tools that run while debugging in VS2015 can vary. For more information on the performance and diagnostic tools in VS2015, check out this blog post from one of my team members (I work at MSFT, and contributed to the tools you're referring to): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2013** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> )

Debug -> Show Diagnostic Tools
[image]

**Visual Studio 2015** (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> )

Debug -> Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging...
[image]